# How can I display Media Player controls with the notification channel?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, debugging, foreground-service

Quite new to Android Programming here so, bear with me if I have done a rookie mistake. I have managed to get my foreground service running well, but I can't see the controls in my notification when I debug and run on my monitoring device except for the labels Prev, Play and Next. I want to see those controls and do something when they are clicked. I also do have some errors in my logcat as below:

```
2020-05-08 12:31:05.567 14495-14495/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"
2020-05-08 12:31:35.063 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
2020-05-08 12:31:35.063 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:31:35.148 14495-14620/net.groupkse.indupendo E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.log.tel_dbg"
2020-05-08 12:31:35.765 14495-14621/net.groupkse.indupendo E/libARC: item map does not been created yet!
2020-05-08 12:31:35.886 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:31:36.261 14495-14621/net.groupkse.indupendo E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
2020-05-08 12:32:33.046 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x9eebc3e0)
2020-05-08 12:32:33.046 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:32:33.120 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:32:40.226 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9eebc3e0)
2020-05-08 12:32:40.226 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:32:40.298 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:07.020 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9eebc3e0)
2020-05-08 12:33:07.020 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:07.092 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:16.921 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9eebc3e0)
2020-05-08 12:33:16.922 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:17.428 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:47.577 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8dfec8a0)
2020-05-08 12:33:47.577 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:47.971 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:48.729 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8dfecb80)
2020-05-08 12:33:48.729 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:48.766 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:53.622 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8dfecb80)
2020-05-08 12:33:53.622 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:54.007 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:59.446 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8dfecf40)
2020-05-08 12:33:59.446 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:33:59.830 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:33:59.970 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8b70fb00)
2020-05-08 12:33:59.970 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:00.068 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:06.971 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8b70fb00)
2020-05-08 12:34:06.972 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:07.014 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:07.659 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8b70fb00)
2020-05-08 12:34:07.659 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:07.701 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.028 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8acd40e0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.028 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.071 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.658 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd40e0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.658 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:27.704 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:30.055 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd40e0)
2020-05-08 12:34:30.055 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:30.382 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:32.015 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8acd4500)
2020-05-08 12:34:32.015 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:32.053 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:36.824 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd4500)
2020-05-08 12:34:36.824 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:36.862 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd4500)
2020-05-08 12:34:36.862 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:37.194 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:37.201 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:41.317 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8acd4920)
2020-05-08 12:34:41.317 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:41.366 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:44.246 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd4920)
2020-05-08 12:34:44.246 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:44.575 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:47.350 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x8acd4dc0)
2020-05-08 12:34:47.350 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:47.396 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:49.349 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x8acd4dc0)
2020-05-08 12:34:49.349 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:49.681 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:52.699 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x890eb2a0)
2020-05-08 12:34:52.699 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:52.735 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:55.546 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x890eb2a0)
2020-05-08 12:34:55.546 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:55.860 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:34:59.521 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x890eb520)
2020-05-08 12:34:59.521 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:34:59.552 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:35:00.624 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: stop called in state 0, mPlayer(0x890eb520)
2020-05-08 12:35:00.624 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:35:00.936 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
2020-05-08 12:35:01.715 14495-15075/net.groupkse.indupendo E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8192; index=8192
        at com.android.okhttp.okio.Buffer.writeByte(Buffer.java:973)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.concatLengthPrefixed(Platform.java:212)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.configureTlsExtensions(Platform.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:187)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:299)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:237)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:472)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:418)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:549)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.seekTo(MediaHTTPConnection.java:212)
        at android.media.MediaHTTPConnection.getMIMEType(MediaHTTPConnection.java:387)
        at android.media.IMediaHTTPConnection$Stub.onTransact(IMediaHTTPConnection.java:89)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
2020-05-08 12:35:12.790 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 4, mPlayer(0x890eb9e0)
2020-05-08 12:35:12.790 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2020-05-08 12:35:12.818 14495-14495/net.groupkse.indupendo E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Here is my Constants.java class:

```
public class Constants {
    public interface ACTION {
        public static String MAIN_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.main";
        public static String PREV_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.prev";
        public static String PLAY_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.prev";
        public static String NEXT_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.next";
        public static String STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.startforeground";
        public static String STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION = "net.groupkse.indupendo.action.stopforeground";
    }

    public interface NOTIFICATION_ID {
        public static int FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;
    }
}
```

then here is my createNotificationChannel methods in a separate class I call NotifyApp.java:

```
public class NotifyApp extends Application {

    // Registering notification channel

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "playerServiceChannel";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        // Creating the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
         /**
          *  CharSequence name = getString(R.string.playerServiceChannel);
            String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT; */
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Player Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

here is some code snippet from my PlayerService.java class:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra("url") != null)
            playStream(intent.getStringExtra("url"));

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i("info", "Start foreground service!");
            showNotification();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
            Log.i("info", "Prev pressed.");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
            Log.i("info", "Play pressed.");
            togglePlayer();

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
            Log.i("info", "Next pressed.");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i("info", "Stop foreground received.");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }

        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void showNotification () {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
        //notificationIntent.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Intent previousIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
        PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, previousIntent, 0);

        Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, playIntent, 0);

        Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);

        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_kwacha_coin);

        int playPauseButtonId = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;

        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            playPauseButtonId = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;

        String labelId = "Play";
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            labelId = "Pause";

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Music Player")
                .setTicker("Playing music")
                .setContentText("My song")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_kwacha_coin)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", ppreviousIntent)
                .addAction(playPauseButtonId, labelId, pplayIntent)
                .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", pnextIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);
    }
```

and finally some from my MainActivity.java class:

```
 private void startStreamService (String url) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
        i.putExtra("url", url);
        i.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        startService(i);
        bindService(i, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

Comment: "Prev", "Play" and "Next" **are** what you'd use for media player controls. Have you tried debugging your `onStartCommand`?

Comment: When I debug the code it's giving Previous, Play and Next without their respective Android native icons.

Comment: You didn't say you want icons there. There are no default or native icons, because your notification actions are not native to Android. If you do want icons there, use `Notification.Action.Builder`, that way of adding actions supports icons.

Comment: but where exactly do I use ```Notification.Action.Builder```?

Comment: Same place where you added actions before.

Comment: Why haven't you typed an answer with the correction you are saying? Because I don't really understand you.

Comment: To make a good answer I'd have to cobble up a sample App (because I don't have one on hand), and test it using your specified Android version, and also then explain which approach then works on what version. I'm lazy, so I thought that instead of just leaving the question fade away in silence, I at least comment with some guiding pointers that may or may not help. I also don't understand what you don't understand in a phrase "use `Notification.Action.Builder` when adding actions to your notification".

Comment: I tried to use it but Java didn't seem to like it. Showed red lines in a lot of places in Android Studio. Remember I made mentioned that I am a newbie to Android and Java programming!